# Prestashop multistore problems when installing second theme

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I have a problem while installing the second theme in a Prestashop multi-shop enviroment.
I've correctly created the second shop (with a different domain) but when I try to install a new theme, I get a blank page with only the store logo.

I've tried many combinations:
- create the second shop with or without share the modules
- install the theme before and after creating the second shop
- install the second theme with or without overriding the previous modules
- Googling a lot ;)

The most succesfull test was when I created a new shop without sharing the modules data + installing the second theme without overriding the module.
The result was a styled empty page (with global.css loaded correctly) but without any content inside.
Moreover all the new-theme's modules where not-installed and not-attached to any hooks

:(

Please, can anyone point me in the right direction to install a **Prestashop multishop with two different themes**?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I've noticed that if the two themes are from the same supplier gives such problems, because the names of the classes and methods are usually the same. the solution is to rename classes and methods, or use another theme from another provider.

Comment: see this post. http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/307529-using-two-themes-with-multistore-option-causes-big-problems/